# No exit stamp leaving Australia

Tags: passports, australia, passport-stamps

I am Iranian passport holder. I was in Australia with temporary visa. While I left Australia, the passport officer did not stamp my exit in the passport.

I am wondering, if he has forgotten to stamp the exit or they don't stamp for everybody. If he has forgotten, would it be a question for the case officer of my next visa application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Australian Customs site](http://www.border.gov.au/EnteringorleavingAustralia/Pages/Departing-travellers.aspx#passport_stamping):

> We no longer stamp Australian passports as a matter of course but
>   should you require evidence of travel you may ask one of our officers
>   to do so.

So no need to be concerned, it won't be a problem in the future. They do record it electronically.

Comment: It talks about **Australian passports** while I am not an Australian.

It is electronic, But it requires that I hope the next case officer is intelligent enough :)

Comment: I have been in and out of Australia several times this year with a non-Australian passport, and had no problems :) (and haven't always been stamped either)

Comment: Other comments online seem to indicate the same, by non-Australian travelers too - [for example](http://www.tripadvisor.com.au/ShowTopic-g255055-i120-k6790301-Did_they_stop_the_exit_passport_stamps-Australia.html)

Comment: Just checked my (Canadian) passport. My 2012 Sydney arrival stamp is partnered with a 2012 Sydney departure stamp; my 2015 arrival stamp has no partner. This non-Australian passport did not get an exit stamp after Dec 2014, in other words.

Comment: I'm a UK passport holder and recently visited Australia (Sydney airport). No stamps in my passport as I used the electronic gates. I asked an officer (standing nearby) about this and he assured me that entries and exits are all recorded electronically. Meanwhile my wife was rejected by the electronic gates and _did_ get an entry stamp in her passport.

Answer (score 1):

Some countries have a general presumption that you departed before you visa expires, so it's not a problem unless you are found in the country after the expiration date. Assuming you departed by a commercial carrier, immigration gets passenger lists from the airline/ cruise company and can match up arrivals with departures that way.

If, for some reason, it does become an issue you just have to provide some evidence that you were somewhere else - work records, boarding pass, entry stamp of another country etc.